# C console application print out $ dollar sign

Tags: c

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("%c", "\n");
}
```

I need to know why is it printing $ on the output,

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Don't specify formats that don't match what you pass.

Comment: I suspect the dollar is the command line prompt

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code but post your code as text.

Comment: If your compiler isn't warning you about that, turn up warnings until it does (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good starting set for gcc and clang).

Answer (score 2):

`%c` is for printing a `char` value, but `"\n"` is a string, which is `char*`.

Either use `%s` to print a string, or use `'\n'` to make a `char` value.

Comment: But why it printed out the $?

Comment: Why not? Anything can happen when you cause undefined behavior. It was treating part of the address as a character.

Answer (score 0):

you’re passing a pointer to an argument taking a char. the dollar is probably the most significant byte  value of your pointer.